# SQL - Remove Duplicate value between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking a simple way to remove an unwanted Duplicate value.

The Dupe is part of a reference to another column, and not within the column itself, but the column I want to remove the dupe value from is multi-delimited with other values.

Here is an example table:

```
ID,Thing
Dog,Cat;Dog;Bird
Snake,Horse;Fish;Snake
Car,Car;Bus;Bike
```

As you can see Dog,Snake,Car are the values I need to remove from the Thing column.

Output:

```
ID,Thing
Dog,Cat;Bird
Snake,Horse;Fish
Car,Bus;Bike
```

Is there a way to match within a multidelimited field and pull out the exact match?

I'm using SQL Server MGMT studio. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I think you can disregard the answer I had below. I just reread your question. I was confused. This is a little more complex than I thought. I think if I was going to tackle this, I would do it in C#. There's a lot to keep track of.

Comment: Are the semi-colons the record delimiters?

Comment: i am a bit confused. Your table has how many columns ? can you please format your sample data properly ?

Comment: I think Dog and Cat are separated by a comma in the Thing column and are the same record. And the next record only has Dog. But I don't know why it would be formatted that way.

Comment: Fix your data model!

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @JohnnySemicolon Please check the answer I provided below and get back to me if you have any queries.  I doubt about your output, if 'id' and 'things' are column names, you should not have a "comma" in between them. they should be separated,

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
      SELECT ID, Thing, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Thing) AS rn
)

DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE rn > 1
```

I believe this will do it. Test first by running just the CTE part of the query so you can see what rn is.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and sample data is not very clear. I *think* what you want is to remove anything from the second column that is in the first column, in which case you can try using `replace`

```
select Id, 
  replace(replace(thing,id,''),';;',';')
from table
```

Storing multi-value elements in a column is *never* a good idea and is a conflict of interest with the relational data model; it pretty much always causes problems at some point.

Comment: This may not gracefully handle `'Dog'` and `'Catfish;Dogfish;Lungfish'`.

Comment: Possibly yes,I'm sure if the OP were to revisit his question and add some clarity it could be easily improved.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is concatenate a leading and a trailing `;` to the value of `Thing` and then replace the value of `ID` with an empty string.
Then remove the leading and trailing `;`.

If your version of SQL Server is 2017+, you can use the function [TRIM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT Id, 
       TRIM(';' FROM REPLACE(';' + Thing + ';', ';' + ID + ';', ';')) Thing
from tablename;
```

For previous versions use [`SUBSTRING()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT Id, 
       SUBSTRING(
         REPLACE(';' + Thing + ';', ';' + ID + ';', ';'),
         2,
         LEN(REPLACE(';' + Thing + ';', ';' + ID + ';', ';')) - 2
       ) Thing
from tablename;
```

If you want to update the table:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Thing = TRIM(';' FROM REPLACE(';' + Thing + ';', ';' + ID + ';', ';'));
```

or:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Thing = SUBSTRING(
              REPLACE(';' + Thing + ';', ';' + ID + ';', ';'),
              2,
              LEN(REPLACE(';' + Thing + ';', ';' + ID + ';', ';')) - 2
            );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb7f288876c1c61f8a37f3b22254ad3b).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what "multi-delimited" means with respect to a string.  In your context it seems to suggest that you might have different types of delimiters.  It definitely does mean  that you have a really poor data model.  If you want to remove the `id` from the `things` column, then my first suggestion is to fix the delimiters.

In SQL Server, you could use:

```
select t.*,
       (select string_agg(s.value, ';')
        from string_split(replace(t.things, ',', ';'), ';') s
        where s.value <> t.id
       ) as new_things
from t;
```

If the delimited have some intrinsic meaning (did I mentioned that you should fix the data model?), then you can use a more brute force approach.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*,
       (case when things = id then ''
             when things like concat(id, '[,;]%')
             then stuff(things, 1, len(id) + 1, '')
             when things like concat('%[,;]', id)
             then left(things, len(things) - len(id) - 1)
             when things like concat('%[,;]', id, '[,;]%')
             then stuff(things, patindex(concat('%[,;]', id, '[,;]%'), things), len(id) + 1, '')
             else things
       end)
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=335aad107b9647e2fc8b51738901bf92) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is a good one. I used simple case statement to get the answer. It is CHARINDEX that helped to find the location of the value in Id column and then identified the position of the value in id and according to the position, string was replaced by required values.

```
 --Preparing the table
 SELECT *
  INTO t
 FROM (VALUES 
         ('Dog', 'Cat;Dog;Bird'),
         ('Snake', 'Horse;Fish;Snake'),
         ('Car', 'Car;Bus;Bike')
 ) v(id, things)


 --Query
SELECT id
    ,CASE   WHEN CHARINDEX(reverse(id), reverse(things), 1)  =  1 THEN  REPLACE(things,';'+id   ,'') 
            WHEN CHARINDEX(id, things, 1)  < LEN(things) AND CHARINDEX(id, things, 1) > 1      THEN   REPLACE(things, id +';'   ,'')  
            WHEN CHARINDEX(id, things, 1) = 1 THEN REPLACE(things, id +';'  ,'') 
            ELSE 'End' 
        END as [things]          
 FROM t
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @JohnnySemicolon have a look in the answer and get back to me if any help is required.